# Count the number of false positives with respect to the first class

Tags: data

Can anybody tell me the formula how to find the number of false positives with respect to the first class?

[image]

where $y$ is the truth / target and $a(x)$ is the prediction

Comment: It would be useful if you posted what $y=i$ and $a(x)=i$ mean. I am not sure what exactly is happening here. Is this a classification problem?

Comment: @learning it is a confusion matrix with three classes

Comment: So  if the column labels indicate the predicted labels and the row labels indicate true labels, then false positives for the first class would be the ones whose true class is 2 or 3, but classified into the first column.

Comment: So row 2 and row 3, column 1 indicate the ones that have different true labels than the ones predicted right? So it should be 5+10.

Comment: it says that's a wrong answer..

Comment: Then maybe I don't know what the true labels are and what the predicted labels are.

Answer (score 0):

I always find the notion of false positive and negative confusing, especially when it comes to multi-class problems.

A good rule of thumb that I came up with is the following

**True positive**: "I predicted that you were a certain class, and I was right"

**False positive**: "I predicted that you were a certain class but I was wrong"

**True negative**: "I predicted that you weren't a certain class, and I was right"

**False negative**: "I predicted that you weren't a certain class, but I was wrong"

So in your case, there are **31** true positives with regard to the first class since you predicted 31 times that something was class 1 but you were wrong.